# SlickGrid column headers not synched when in Full Screen mode

Tags: slickgrid

We have a serious problem with SlickGrid in an application.
The problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with the way we implement/built the Grid since the behavior is reproducable on every SlickGrid I've seen.

Here's the problem:
If the User is viewing a grid on less than FullScreen mode and scolls the grid horizontally, then snaps the browser to fullScreen, the column headers are out of sync with the column contents.  This wouldn't be a problem if the Horz scrollbar was retained (scrolling even 1px resynch's columns/contents) but if the grid fits inside the window, there is no Horz scrollbar and no way to resynch the columns with the content.

What we need is a method to repaint the column Headers without repainting the entire grid or a patch from someone who has already solved this.

These have no effect:

```
Options:
syncColumnCellResize:true

Method:
grid.resizeCanvas();
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the fix submitted in https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/commit/c5324a130ae2ef496f2c007f736f805cc7caa3f0 (get the latest code at https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/zipball/v2.0).

Comment: It didn't like this: if (!initialized) { return; } but when this was removed, it solved the issue

Comment: Can you post a repro on jsfiddle.net